# How can i find all digits in a string using regexps in python

Tags: python, regex

Hello iam trying to find all the degits in a string but it returns an empty list

my code :

```
import re
re.findall(r'/d','5585858')
>>>> []
```

what is the error please ?

Comment: It's `\d`. Not `/d` as you've written.

Comment: What about [c for c in s if "0" <= c <= "9"]

Comment: That's good too, although I prefer to check whether a character is a digit with `isdigit()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong pattern, you need `\d` first and for get all of digits you can add `+` to `\d` for match 1 or more combine of digits :

```
re.findall(r'\d+','5585858')
```

Also based on your string you can use other functions like `re.search` that may be more efficient.

And if you want to convert your string to list you can simply use `list` :

```
>>> list('5585858')
['5', '5', '8', '5', '8', '5', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `'\d+'` instead of `'/d'`

```
 >>> import re
 >>> re.findall(r'\d+', '5585858')
 ['5585858']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regular expression for that.

```
>>> [number for number in '5585a858' if number.isdigit()]
['5', '5', '8', '5', '8', '5', '8']
```